Want to know the inernal mach of Numba JIT
From https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/binding/examples.html, I made up the following code, aiming to understand the procedure of Numba JIT.

from __future__ import print_function

from ctypes import CFUNCTYPE, c_double, c_float

import llvmlite.binding as llvm


# All these initializations are required for code generation!
llvm.initialize()
llvm.initialize_native_target()
llvm.initialize_native_asmprinter()  
from numba import njit

@njit('float32(float32,float32)')
def foo(x,y):
    return x+y

llvm_str = foo.inspect_llvm(foo.signatures[0])

print(llvm_str)
print("------------------")

llvm_ir = llvm_str

def create_execution_engine():
    """
    Create an ExecutionEngine suitable for JIT code generation on
    the host CPU.  The engine is reusable for an arbitrary number of
    modules.
    """
    # Create a target machine representing the host
    target = llvm.Target.from_default_triple()
    target_machine = target.create_target_machine()
    # And an execution engine with an empty backing module
    backing_mod = llvm.parse_assembly("")
    engine = llvm.create_mcjit_compiler(backing_mod, target_machine)
    return engine

def compile_ir(engine, llvm_ir):
    """
    Compile the LLVM IR string with the given engine.
    The compiled module object is returned.
    """
    # Create a LLVM module object from the IR
    mod = llvm.parse_assembly(llvm_ir)
    mod.verify()
    # Now add the module and make sure it is ready for execution
    engine.add_module(mod)
    engine.finalize_object()
    engine.run_static_constructors()
    return mod

engine = create_execution_engine()
mod = compile_ir(engine, llvm_ir)

# Look up the function pointer (a Python int)
# func_ptr = engine.get_function_address("fpadd")
func_ptr = engine.get_function_address("foo")

# Run the function via ctypes
# cfunc = CFUNCTYPE(c_double, c_double, c_double)(func_ptr)
cfunc = CFUNCTYPE(c_float, c_float, c_float)(func_ptr)
res = cfunc(1.0, 3.5)
# print("fpadd(...) =", res)
print("foo(...) =", res)


But, I got following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_llvmwithNumbaGetLLVMIR5.py", line 63, in 
res = cfunc(1.0, 3.5)
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
I guess the error is because the IR instance of foo() is not OK. But, I really have no idea how to cope with it.
